# FFmpeg RTSP error: Nonmatching transport in server reply

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am using FFmpeg to read an rtsp camera. I am getting an error: `ffmpeg rtsp error: Nonmatching transport in server reply` in C++ and `Invalid data found when processing input`. The camera has setting "RTP ES". Here is the code.

```
source_name = "rtsp://192.168.1.108/WESCAM";

// Open the initial context variables that are needed
format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();    
codec_ctx = NULL;

// Register everything
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
   
//open RTSP camera or h264 file
if (avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, source_name, NULL, NULL) != 0) 
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: I can play this VLC using the rtsp address shown above.  I'm using RedHat 6.9.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66280861/1207193) might help you

Answer (score 0):

may this helpful:

```
AVDictionary *opts = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "udp", 0); // here "udp" can replaced by "tcp"
avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, rtsp_addr, nullptr, &opts);
...
av_dict_free(&opts);
```

Comment: please give a Little more Information, like what does it do, and how it solves OPs problem

Comment: Thanks - I have already tried that and it is still not working but is getting a different error.  
“Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size: 
Consider increasing the value for the ‘analyzeduration’ and ‘probesize’ options”

When I issue the commands
codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(codec_ctx, codec);
avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codecpar);

The width and height of the stream is 0

I'm using a VITEC MGW NANO dencoder